# XML schema still allowing duplicate id's with unique

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to design an XML schema for books where a unique ID needs to be specified for each book entry. However it just doesn't seem to work. Below is the XSD i am using,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="BookShelf">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Shelf" type="ShelfType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="ShelfType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="Book">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:token"/>
      <xs:element name="Language" type="xs:language"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:unique name="unique-bookId">
    <xs:selector xpath="Book"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The XML I am trying to validate with this is,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<BookShelf>
    <Description>My bookshelf</Description>
    <Shelf>
        <Book id="1">
            <Title>Seitsemän veljestä</Title>
            <Language>fi</Language>
        </Book>
        <Book id="1">
            <Title>Another title</Title>
            <Language>en</Language>
        </Book>
    </Shelf>
</BookShelf>
```

which is validating fine even though it should not (I've used the same id for 2 entries). I'm pretty new at XML and would appreciate if someone could please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got the `<xs:unique>` in the wrong place - it needs to be inside the definition of the *ancestor* element within which the `Book` elements should be unique, not in the `Book` element definition itself.  The following would force Book ids to be unique within each shelf, but would allow the same ID on different shelves:

```
  <xs:element name="BookShelf">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Shelf" type="ShelfType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10">
          <xs:unique name="unique-bookId">
            <xs:selector xpath="Book"/><!-- selects books on this shelf -->
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
          </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

If instead you want the IDs to be globally unique across all shelves then put the unique constraint at the `BookShelf` level and adjust the selector appropriately:

```
  <xs:element name="BookShelf">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Shelf" type="ShelfType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="unique-bookId">
      <xs:selector xpath="Shelf/Book"/><!-- selects books on all shelves -->
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
```

For future reference, note that if your schema had a `targetNamespace` then those selectors would not work as-is, because unprefixed names in selector XPaths always mean "no namespace".  You would need to add `xmlns:tns="<target namespace URI>"` to your `xs:schema` element and then use a selector of `tns:Shelf/tns:Book`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you specifically need to use digits as ID values? If not, one possibility is using `xs:ID` as the `id` attribute type instead of `xs:string`:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
```

That way only [unique XML identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xml-id-20040407/) are allowed as values of the `id` attribute. A valid XML identifier can't start with a digit, however, so you'll have to change your ID type to something like `id-1`, for example.